# A converse to Cauchy's integral formula

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

Suppose that $D$ is a simply connected domain whose boundary is given by a smooth Jordan curve. Suppose furthermore that $f:\partial D \to \mathbb{C}$ is a Hölder continuous function. The Cauchy integral formula yields a holomorphic function
$$
u:D\to \mathbb{C},\quad u(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial D}\frac{f(\xi)}{\xi-z}d{\xi}
$$
My question is the following:

> Under what conditions can we guarantee that $u(z) \to f(z_0)$ as $z\to z_0$ for every $z_0 \in \partial D$?

By a general Cauchy's theorem, a necessary condition is
$$
\int_{\partial D} f(\xi)d{\xi} = 0.
$$
I saw a post a few days ago (can't find the post anymore) which stated that the condition
$$
\int_{\partial D} f(\xi)\xi^kd{\xi} = 0.
$$
for all $k\geq 0$ is sufficient but I can't figure out a proof for this. Is this true? Ideas on how to approach the problem are also appreciated!

Comment: Consider $u(z)$ also for $|z|>1$ defined by the same formula, though the power series expansion is in positive powers of $\xi$ and negative powers of $z$ and show that $u(z) - u(\frac{1}{\bar z})$ is the Poisson integral of $f$, calls it $v(z)$ for $|z| < 1$ and then you can conclude since you know the Poisson integral converges to its boundary, so $u(z)$ converges to $f(z)$ if and only if $u(\frac {1}{\bar z})$ is identically zero

Comment: With convergence a.e. one can assume only $f$ integrable and conclude same - $u$ converges a.e. to $f$ if and only if the Poisson integral of $f$ is analytic if and only if the Cauchy integral is identically zero on the exterior of the unit disc if and only if the integrals you wanted are zero. This gives equivalent representations of the Hardy class $H^1$.

Comment: @Conrad I'm trying to make sense of your comments but I'm at a bit of a loss. Should I power expand $1/(\xi-z)$ in the integral?

Comment: The proof I sketched works for a disk only and it essentially uses the Poisson formula - a straightforward computation shows that $\frac{e^{it}}{e^{it}-re^{i\theta}} - \frac{re^{i(t-\theta)}}{re^{i(t-\theta)}-1}$ = $P_r{(t-\theta)}$, so $u(z) - u(\frac{1}{\bar z})$ is indeed the  Poisson integral of f; since for $|z| >1$, $\frac{1}{e^{it}-z}$ = $\frac{1}{z}\sum_{k \geq 0}{\frac{e^{ikt}}{z^k}}$, the property $\int_{\partial D} f(\xi)\xi^kd{\xi} = 0$ implies $u$ vanishes for $|z| > 1$ by the above, so indeed for $|z| < 1$, so $|\frac{1}{\bar z}| > 1$, $u$ is the Poisson integral of $f$

Comment: For a general $D$, the proof uses a Riemann mapping, pulling everything to the unit disc (since by Caratheodory theorem that extends to a homeomorphism of the closed disk to the closed Jordan domain $D$); the Cauchy integral on $D$ is decomposed into a Cauchy integral on the unit disk and an integral that is of the type $fG$ where $G$ is an analytic function on $D$, continuos on the boundary; using Runge's theorem, $G$ is uniformly approximable by polynomials, so $\int_{\partial D} f(\xi)\xi^kd{\xi} = 0$ implies the second integral is zero and we can apply the result on the disk.

Comment: The result is called Privalov's Theorem and the above sketch is adapted from Duren's book on $H^p$ spaces, and there is another proof in Goluzin's famous Geometric Theory of Functions of a Complex Variable

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, I'll look into that!

Comment: No problem - the result is quite non-trivial even for the disk though there it is contained in the famous riesz brothers theorem about analytic measures; for arbitrary Jordan domains even with some regularity, while the result is still true, there are a few subtleties since there are are 2 generally distinct hardy spaces and the cauchy transform belongs to the less used one (the one defined by integral norms on curves converging to the boundary rather than the usual one defined by harmonic majorants)

Comment: @Conrad I'm not entirely sure where the Holder continuity condition plays in. Does the result still hold if $f$ is only assumed to be continuous?

Comment: $f$ absolutely integrable w.r. arclength of the boundary curve is enough if you allow convergence a.e. When the boundary is smooth enough then f continuous enough if you want convergence everywhere